# Book about family with wings, and the protagonist has to learn how to fly(?)

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I remember the book because I really liked it while I was in elementary school (19 now). But the premise was that the girl's family all had wings on their backs that they kept tucked tightly so they could operate like normal humans. However, as the story evolves, something changes and the girl slowly learns to use her wings to fly (which none of her family has done before).

The little girl was in either middle or high school. Please help because I really want to find this book again.

I'm about 45% certain the title even had "wings" in it.

Comment: Hi there, welcome! :) This is a good start, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) to see if it triggers any more memories, such as the language it was written in, what the cover looked like... All this to have a better chance at identifying your story. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be Lauren Winter's *[Growing Wings](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/28744206?book_show_action=true)*?

[image: Book Cover - *Growing Wings*]

> Eleven-year-old Linnet is growing wings from her shoulder blades. She is shocked, but her mother Sarah expected it; after all, she began to grow wings at about the same age -- but her mother cut them off. Linnet and Sarah don't know what to do, but Linnet stumbles into a community of people like her, who live in a secluded place in the mountains, under the threat of exposure. I thought the premise was unusual and interesting, but it wasn't developed enough to really grab me.

It was first published in 2000, which means it was out when you were in Elementary School. It involves "wings" in the title and hereditary wings which must be hidden or removed. They generally can't fly, but the reviews suggest that Linnet does manage flight by the end.

Comment: Oh man, I feel kinda embarrassed to have looked up the same question just to see it was answered years later  but yes! Thank you, this was it!

Comment: No worries. Glad you came back. :)